# When boot into a live Lubuntu from a bootable flash drive, what filesystems on the disk are mounted automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, live-usb

Assume a computer has Lubuntu installed on its disk. Booting into a live Lubuntu from a bootable flash drive is often a way to access filesystems on the disk that are required to be not mounted. So I think understanding what filesystems on the disk are automatically mounted by live OS, and what not, is useful.

When boot into a live Lubuntu from a bootable flash drive, what filesystems on the disk are mounted automatically?

- Is it correct that `/home` on the disk is not mounted, if it is a filesystem itself?
- I can still access  the logical volume files under `/dev/mapper/` on the disk in the same way. So is  `/` on the disk still mounted or not or just partially mounted?
- what about other filesystems on the disk if any?

Thanks.

Comment: Running `mount` will show what's mounted. What's actually mounted depends on many things.

Answer (score 1):

- Partitions *contain* filesystems like an envelope snugly fit inside another
- `mount` will show mounted file-systems as @kashyap said
- `blkid` or better [lsblk](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-lsblk-command/) will show all file-system details
- [gparted](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) will give you a visual picture at the outer (partition) level. And inside (FS) if you click the suitable partition. Though you should be careful you can **lose your data** if you misuse this one